# How to convert price from Pounds to Bitcoin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm looking to convert a price from Pounds to Bitcoin i'm using [Bitcoin conversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcoin-conversion) to do it. Using the following code I can log the Bitcoin price in the console but how do I show the result on the page of my Next.JS application.

Thanks for looking!

```
import { fiatToBitcoin } from 'bitcoin-conversion';
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export async function getBitcoinPrice(price) {
  const paymentInBtcFromGbp = await fiatToBitcoin(price, 'GBP') 
  return paymentInBtcFromGbp
}

export default function ProductPageContent({ product }) {
  const gdp = product.variants.edges[0].node.priceV2.amount
  const [Bitcoin, setBitcoin] = useState()

  getBitcoinPrice(gdp).then(data => {
    setBitcoin(data)
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(String(Bitcoin))}
      <p>Send {String(Bitcoin)} BTC to</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `getBitcoinPrice(gdp).then(...)` is running on every render of the component.

Put that code in a `useEffect` hook like this.

```
import { fiatToBitcoin } from 'bitcoin-conversion';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export async function getBitcoinPrice(price) {
  const paymentInBtcFromGbp = await fiatToBitcoin(price, 'GBP') 
  return paymentInBtcFromGbp
}

export default function ProductPageContent({ product }) {
  const gdp = product.variants.edges[0].node.priceV2.amount
  const [Bitcoin, setBitcoin] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    getBitcoinPrice(gdp).then(data => {
      setBitcoin(data);
      console.log(String(Bitcoin));
    });
  }, [gdp]);

  

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Send {String(Bitcoin)} BTC to</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Samathingamajig - I just tried that but now it's printing undefined in the console and then the correct value but not showing the result on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: It printout out `undefined` the first time because on the first render it is undefined. After that, on the second render, it would print out normally. I have moved the console.log into the `.then`. What is the type of `data`/`Bitcoin`?

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks!